# Наследование и конструкторы с++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, конструктор

Изучаю с++, не могу понять как использовать наследование конструкторов. Пытаюсь вызвать конструктор родительского класса и передать туда параметры, но среда разработки ругается. Почему- не могу понять. Искал в интернете примеры похожие, но ничего связанного с моим случаем не нашёл (имею в виду случай, когда используется отделение реализации с помощью cpp и h файлов). Вот сам код:

File.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class File
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string magic;
    std::string hash;
    std::string owner;
    std::string system;
    std::string date_changed;
    std::string date_created;
    std::string format;
    std::string type;

    float size;

    File(std::string magic, std::string format);

};
```

File.cpp  с реализацией конструктора

```
#include "File.h"
#include <string>

File::File(std::string magic, std::string format) {
    this->magic = magic;
    this->format = format;
};
```

файл Zip.h

```
#pragma once
#include "File.h"
class Zip :
    public File
{
public:

    int number_of_files_inside;

    Zip() : File("504b0304", "zip");
};
```

файл Zip.cpp

```
#include "Zip.h"


Zip::Zip() :File("504b0304", "zip") {}
```

Comment: Убери из **Zip.h** `:File("504b0304", "zip")`

Comment: в файле Zip.h оставил конструктор Zip();

в файле Zip.cpp: Zip::Zip(): File("504b0304", "zip") {}. Однако среда разработки все равно ругается в этом месте..
https://prnt.sc/rci9ib

Comment: Прошу прощения, это моя невнимательность. Конструктор был с модификатором private...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты пытаешься дважды сделать реализацию конструктора Zip.

это не валидный код.

```
 Zip() : File("504b0304", "zip");
```

так как в конструкторе код после `:` относится к реализации, а не объявлению

Answer (score 2):

У вас два раза вызывается конструктор предка - в declaration и в definition вашего конструктора потомка. Два раза - нельзя, один раз - достаточно.

File.h

Сделаем конструктор из приватного в протектед для всех наследников.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class File
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string magic;
    std::string hash;
    std::string owner;
    std::string system;
    std::string date_changed;
    std::string date_created;
    std::string format;
    std::string type;

    float size;

protected:
    File(std::string magic, std::string format);
};
```

Zip.h

Так как конструктор пустой, сделаем его inline в теле класса и сразу скажем какой конструктор предка вызывать.

```
#pragma once
#include "File.h"
class Zip :
    public File
{
public:
    int number_of_files_inside;

    Zip() : File("504b0304", "zip") {}
};
```

Zip.cpp

Здесь ничего не надо уже.

```
#include "Zip.h"
```

Comment: Спасибо за исправление в файле File.h.  Ошибся с модификатором доступа. 
Есть ли принципиальная разница в вашем решении и решении другого автора комментария, который предложил в Zip.cpp вынести реализацию, а в Zip.h оставить только Zip()?

Comment: Как мне думается: 1) inline немного быстрее могут быть, а так как тело конструктора пустое - сам бог велел его сделать inline. 2) сразу в классе все видно - и объявление, и реализацию